# Drawing dynamically positioned overlays on Images in wpf

Tags: wpf, image, mvvm, shapes, overlays

I have an Image control in my view bound to BitmapSource prop in my View Model. This property is updated with images from a camera in my Model class. To get started with drawing shapes on images (so 1 control ON another),after
reading a similar post, I tried the following with a simple Rectangle
shape with Zindex=2 so it should act as an overlay over the image. But the
below doesn't work & all I see is the image from the camera

```
<Canvas>
        <DockPanel Width="400" Height="250">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   Content="IMAGE FROM CAMERA" Width="Auto"/>

            <Image x:Name="CamImageDisplay" 
                     DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                     Source="{Binding  CurrentImage, Mode=OneWay}"   
                     Stretch="None" Width="Auto"/>

            <Rectangle  Width="10" Height="5"
                        Fill="CadetBlue" 
                        Panel.ZIndex="2"  />
        </DockPanel>

    </Canvas>
```

I come from an MFC background where drawing shapes on bitmaps was as
easy as calling Draw3dRect(...). Having said that, my goal is to draw
a collection of shapes (just rectangles & circles) that will have
different co ordinates with each new image.

Could some one please
explain in simple terms or point to some reference that will show how
I can achieve this. Yes, there are other similar questions, but they
are really not quite aligned with my objectives. Thank you & please ask for clarifications if I am unclear in how I have asked my question.

Comment: DockPanel is certainly not the appropriate layout Panel. Put the Image and the Rectangle in a common Canvas, which allows absolute positioning. That said, setting ZIndex is redundant as long you declare the Rectangle after the Image.

Comment: How many shapes are you expecting at max? If they are a few, you could choose a MVVM solution. If there will be hundreds or thousands of them, you will have to go a 'manual drawing' way.

Comment: There will be about 20-30 shapes for an image. Each iteration, the image changes & so will the co ordinates of the shapes.